# How do I categorise and plot data from a Pandas dataframe using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a `DataFrame` of Tweet values and want to plot a graph of `'Favourites'` against `'Date'` and categorise/colour-code the data by `'User'`.

I am able to get a scatter or bar plot of the data but cannot get a working solution to categorise based on the `'User'`. The `'Date'` also comes out as messy in the graph and I am unable to understand the cause of this problem.

I have tried using [this tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#basic-plotting-plot) to get a line graph but don't understand how to apply it to my `DataFrame`

#### DataFrame Structure

```
data_frame = pandas.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets], columns=['Tweets'])

data_frame['User'] = numpy.array([tweet.user.screen_name for tweet in tweets])
data_frame['ID'] = numpy.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])
data_frame['Length'] = numpy.array([len(tweet.text) for tweet in tweets])
data_frame['Date'] = numpy.array([tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets])
data_frame['Source'] = numpy.array([tweet.source for tweet in tweets])
data_frame['Favourites'] = numpy.array([tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets])
data_frame['Retweets'] = numpy.array([tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets])

return data_frame
```

#### Plotting

```
x = result.Date
y = result.Favourites

plt.xlabel("Date", fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel("Favourites", fontsize=10)


plt.figure(figsize=(30,30))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


plt.scatter(x,y)

plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

I want the graph to show a line graph of `Favourites` against time with the different `User`s colour coded something like in the below example:[image: this example]

My current output is this: [image: this]

#### Sample Data

[image: Output]

[Raw paste](https://pastebin.com/sdwryY1Y)

Comment: I tried this and the output is ![bizarre](https://i.imgur.com/pOvCX84.png)

Comment: What does the Favourites data look like. Try `plt.plot(x,y,'ro')`.

Comment: Added sample data to main post

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide a solution without looking at the exact data. Perhaps this is worth a try.

```
for user in data_frame.User.unique():
     d = data_frame[data_framef['User']==user]
     plt.plot(d['Date'],d['Favourites'],'o')

plt.plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Favorites':['100','200','300'] ,'Date':['02/20/2015','01/15/2016','08/21/2015']})
df['Date'] =pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df=df.sort_values("Date")
x=df.Date
y=df.Favorites
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

From the image you provided, I saw that there are zig-zag lines when plotting to try to sort the data frame by date and then plot it.